# Tweet a picture with OAuth

Tags: twitter, oauth

I am using the following code for Tweeting pictures with OAuth. I have found this identical code in several tutorials however I cant get it to work while no errors occur.

```
<?php
// Insert your keys/tokens
$consumerKey = '***';
$consumerSecret = '***';
$OAuthToken = '***';
$OAuthSecret = '***';

// Full path to twitterOAuth.php (change OAuth to your own path)
require_once('connect/twitter/twitteroauth.php');

$params = array(
    'status' => 'Testing API http://google.com',
    'media[]' => 'http://diit.cz/sites/default/files/google_chrome_logo.png'
);

// create new instance
$tweet = new TwitterOAuth($consumerKey, $consumerSecret, $OAuthToken, $OAuthSecret);

// Send tweet
$tweet->post('statuses/update', $params);
?>
```

Just to be sure. Shall the $OAuthToken and $OAuthSecret be copied from Twitter dev? Or are these variables different for each individual user?

I have checked so far for errors in copying twitter keys and secrets, checked whether the twitteroatuh.php file is properly linked, checked whether my Twitter App is set to Read/Write permissions, checked whether cURL is enabled on my server.

Upon executing this code, no errors occur and nothing is posted to my Twitter.

Comment: The media has to be a local image - you can't simply post a URL. Have use tried saving the image on your server and posting that?

Comment: Yes I tried that. It tweets the test but no image